# Flask App on Docker Image and Docker-compose.yml cannot import "app"

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I tried to deploy a flask app project. When I directly docker-compose up --build is working but when I create the image and save&load to another place my same docker-compose.yml file cannot run properly. The error is cannot import "app".

## working area:

- Dockerfile
- docker-compose.yml
- src/app.py

## not working era:

- image.tar file(which is using for docker load)
- docker-compose.yml

### Dockerfile:

```
RUN mkdir /app

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/src

COPY requirements.txt /app/src/requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


ENV FLASK_APP="app.py"

EXPOSE 5005

CMD python -u -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
```

### docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5005:5005"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    expose:
      - 5005
```

### src/app.py:

```
if __name__ == "__app__":
    # start up api
    app.run(port=5005, debug=True, host="0.0.0.0")
```

The result of docker-compose up on the not working era is **Error:cannot import "app"**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `docker-compose.yml` file wouldn't work on a machine where the application code doesn't exist because of the volume mount defined here

```yaml
    volumes:
      - .:/app
```

This volume mount will tell Docker to take whatever's in the `.` directory of the host machine and mount it to the `/app` directory on the container.  In this case, on your machine where the app doesn't run, you mentioned that the application code doesn't exist in this directory, so it would make sense that the application doesn't run. If you remove the volume mount from the `docker-compose.yml` file on the second machine and try to run the container again, things should work normally as long as your application code is all copied over to the image correctly. You can read more about Docker volumes [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).

Answer (score 0):

try this dockerfile code

```
# using python 3.11
FROM python:3.11

# set a directory for the app
WORKDIR /projectname

# copy all the files to the container
COPY . .

# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# tell the port number the container should expose
EXPOSE 5005
CMD [ "python", "app.py" ]
```